# Does the addition of a colon after class name cause an error?

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

I've encountered a question in a java exam that asks us to find **four** compilation errors in the presented code, which was the following :

```
interface Movable{
    protected void g(){System.out.println("Hello")};
}
class Vehicle : java.lang.Object{
    private int x;
}
public class Main extends Vehicle, Movable{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("this is main");     
    }
    public void g() {
        this.x= 2;
    }
}
```

now, I've managed to find all four errors, the "protected" in an interface, the body of the method in an interface, the missing keyword "Implements", and the variable x which can't be accessed by g().
my question is about this part

```
Vehicle : java.lang.Object
```

when i tried to run this code after i fixed the four errors , it showed another error in this line saying '{' expected after Vehicle.

**is it really an error or is this another way of extending a class in java?**

Comment: it's really an error

Comment: Believe the compiler.  It knows the language much better than you do.  That syntax is C++, C#, Kotlin, but not Java.

Comment: There are at least two further errors beyond that in the above (no `;` after the call to `System.out.println`, but one *after* the closing `}` on that function body). If the exam thinks there are only four errors in that code, you might want to consider whether the people behind it really are the ones to learn from. :-) (But if they said **at least** four errors, that's different.)

Comment: You **implement** an interface, not extend it. Moreso, a class can't extend two classes.

Comment: If you replace `protected` with `default`, two errors would become one error, because now the implementation would be allowed. Colon `:` is definitely an error.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you use the `extends` keyword to subclass other classes, and `implements` for interfaces. The colon is used in C# and some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one error - in Java there's a single inheritance and therefore class Main cannot wxtend both Vehicle and Movable.
The semicolon notation in class Vehicle is also not a valid Java syntax.